# In MySQL, can I UPDATE a value based on a count of certain characters in another column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update a column in a database with the count of certain characters in another column. Specifically, I need SQL to turn this:

```
Col1    | Col2
1/2/3   | 0
1/3     | 0
1/2/3/2 | 0
1       | 0
```

Into this:

```
Col1    | Col2
1/2/3   | 2
1/3     | 1
1/2/3/2 | 3
1       | 0
```

Is it possible? Because it seems like it should be possible.

I've been looking around and all I've found is that regular expressions aren't supported in MySQL and I really need to do this directly rather than using another language (so, for example, a simple PHP script to do this won't work for me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE your_table 
SET Col2 = CHAR_LENGTH(Col1) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(Col1, '/', ''));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE t SET col2=select (length(col1) - length(replace(col1, '/',''))) FROM t
```